# Unable to locate element: python + selennium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I am trying to click on the drop-down shown in the figure

[image]

This is what I have tried

```
select = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='chosen-container chosen-container-single']//a[@class='chosen-single chosen-single-with-deselect chosen-default']//input[@class='chosen-search-input']")
select.click()
```

But it give me this error

> NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:
>   //div[@class='chosen-container
>   chosen-container-single']//a[@class='chosen-single
>   chosen-single-with-deselect
>   chosen-default']//input[@class='chosen-search-input']

I tried the solution given by Sameer but now it gives me this error

> ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element  is not
>   clickable at point (228,398) because another element  obscures it

Comment: In screenshot you have correct simple css selector for the input: `input.chosen-search-input`!

Comment: @Sers actually there are 5 more drop-downs with the same css, so it always opens the first one

Comment: Can you share the URL? Try WebDriverWait, see @KunduK answer.

Comment: @Sers  [https://portal.gmpplus.org/en-US/cdb/certified-companies/#]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the dropdown contains an unique text, you can find the element by using that text in the xpath.

**Try this updated xpath**
You xpath should be like:

```
select = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='textfilter_scopes_chosen']")
select.click()
```

*Updating the answer to get the element by a better approach*

As an unique id is present for the element, you should use that as `id` is faster than xpath.
You can use the id like:

```
select = browser.find_element_by_id("textfilter_scopes_chosen")
select.click()
```

Comment: I just tried this but it's giving me another error. I'll update my question so u can see it

Comment: @KevinKurien what is the error that you got? And can you check if an iframe is present in the html structure?

Comment: @KevinKurien try the updated way to click on the element and let me know if it works

Comment: I tried the updated answer, now it does not show any error but it does not cick the drop-down either.It just loads the page and scrolls down to where the dropdown is

Comment: @KevinKurien try the updated xpath, i have verified it, its working fine.

Comment: @KevinKurien Great, though i have update my answer as an `id` is present for that element so you should fetch the element by the id. I have mentioned the approach in my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

In order to click on the `dropdown` element induce `WebDriverWait`() and `element_to_be_clickable`() and following `XPATH` option.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='chosen-container chosen-container-single']//a[.//span[text()='Please select a scope']]"))).click()
```

You need to import following libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: webdriverwait give this error `TimeoutException: Message: `

Comment: @KevinKurien : It was my mistake i have just missed the last bracket `]` in my earlier answer.